# Why kendo tab strip is not getting the tab id defined in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-tabstrip

I have this code which was working before updated my Kendo version. What I'm trying to do is depending the selected tab option execute some other code, this is what I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="tabs1">
    <ul>
      <li id="tabs1-user" style="display:none;">Bullets</li>
      <li id="tabs1-superUser">Features</li>
      <li id="tabs1-details">Details</li>
      <li id="tabs1-dashboard">Info</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
      setTabs();
    });
    
    function setTabs() {
        var t1 = $("#tabs1").kendoTabStrip({
                animation: { open: { duration: 0, effects: "fadeIn" }, close: { duration: 0, effects: "fadeOut" } },
                select: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
        
                    if (e && e.item) {
                        switch (e.item.id) {
                            case 'tabs1-user': break;
                            case 'tabs1-details': getDetails(); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            t1.select(0);
            $("#tabs1").show(); 
    }
    
    function getDetails() {
        console.log('calling method to retrieve details...'); 
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here is a [DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UsoBUfEW)

As you can see I expect sending the Id **tabs1-details** when I click on Details tab but what I'm getting is **tabs1-tab-3**.

How can I solve this issue? I need to define the tabs name in somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Kendo Tabstrip overrides the ID you created. In this case, my suggestion would be to use the `data` attribute. Something like `data-id`. Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.3.1207/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="tabs1">
    <ul>
      <li data-id="tabs1-user" style="display:none;">Bullets</li>
      <li data-id="tabs1-superUser">Features</li>
      <li data-id="tabs1-details">Details</li>
      <li data-id="tabs1-dashboard">Info</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
      setTabs();
    });
    
    function setTabs() {
        var t1 = $("#tabs1").kendoTabStrip({
                animation: { open: { duration: 0, effects: "fadeIn" }, close: { duration: 0, effects: "fadeOut" } },
                select: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
        
                    if (e && e.item) {
                        switch ($(e.item).attr('data-id')) {
                            case 'tabs1-user': break;
                            case 'tabs1-details': getDetails(); break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            t1.select(0);
            $("#tabs1").show(); 
    }
    
    function getDetails() {
        console.log('calling method to retrieve details...'); 
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above code, when you click Details, "calling method to retrieve details..." will be printed in the console log.